# NPX Prisma Unexpected end of JSON input Exception

Tags: node.js, prisma

After a migration of my database schema and updating node and the prisma client to the latest stable I get following exception when starting "npx prisma studio"

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ****/node_modules/prisma/prisma-client/runtime/index.js:28174:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Currently I'm stuck and don't know where I can get more log information around the exception.

Comment: What is your node and prisma version?